# What is this part on my new cooktop?

Tags: kitchens, appliances

I just got a Samsung NA36N7755TS cooktop secondhand. In between the rings of the power burner, there is a little metal part sticking up. It came significantly bent (damaged in transport). I bent it back mostly upright with a wrench, but I’m not sure what it actually is or is supposed to be doing. I can’t find it in any of the drawings of the cooktop. Does anyone know what it is? Thanks!  [image: image of unknown part on burner]

[image]

Comment: Is there one of these on each burner? If it only on this one burner, then it might be a temperature sensor. It might be a burner that has automatic control to keep a saucepan at a constant temp, usually below boiling.

Comment: It’s only on this burner.

Comment: The logic of bending things when dealing with gas escapes me - an entry for a Darwin Award maybe…

Comment: I mean this is clearly not a part of the gas system… I’m trying to figure out what this is so I can decide whether I need to replace it

Comment: Looks like an igniter for a gas burner.

Comment: @JonCuster the igniter is on the other side, as seen in bottom picture ... there is even a lightning bolt icon next to it

Comment: the metal part looks like it has a flat side ... it may be an adjustment control

Comment: @jsotola I think the flat bit is from where something smacked into it and bent it haha. I found that this is built onto the burner cup assembly… still not sure what it is though!

Comment: https://partsdr.com/part/dg62-00162a-burner-cup-orifice?gclid=CjwKCAjw2f-VBhAsEiwAO4lNeBFq4lwLx3YgcBv-uwDdc9y_ocqT9yfp8EyNQ2KNJmM_z7bACv0LZBoCbHUQAvD_BwE

Comment: What makes you think it was bent in transit, rather than designed to be bent? It seems rather unlikely that a recessed part like that would be damaged in transit.

Comment: @JackAidley the whole cooktop got pretty beat up in transit (even the metal grating was damaged). I am having to replace several parts on it that were damaged. I was able to find images of the bent prong on a new cooktop and confirm that it is straight on that cooktop.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! This appears to be a thermocouple designed for flame out detection: https://www.sinopts.com/How-important-is-the-flameout-protection-device-id3688335.html

Update: I'm not actually sure this is a functional thermocouple. See below.

Comment: Then there should be one on each burner.

Comment: @JACK Assuming this cooktop is like mine, the other burners have only a single burner/cap/etc. instead of two. In which case, the thermocouples for the others may be underneath the cap instead of between the cap and ring.

Comment: @JACK I actually have a suspicion about this. Here is another stove which seems to use the exact same power burner, made by Defendi SRL: https://www.homedepot.com/p/ROBAM-30-in-Gas-Cooktop-in-Stainless-Steel-with-4-Burners-including-20-000-BTU-Burner-ROBAM-G413/320110077

Comment: If you look at the second-to-last pic, you see that everything about that power burner looks identical to mine, except for the thermocouple which looks different (brass base, pointed tip instead of silver prong). Then, if you look at the burner cup part for my Samsung range, you see that the prong in question is actually built into the burner cup and has no wire leads coming from it as you might expect: https://partsdr.com/part/dg62-00162a-burner-cup-orifice

Comment: Also, the Robam cooktop explicitly advertises flameout protection, while the Samsung does not. So, unless the thermocouple-based flameout mechanism is somehow sneakily self-contained inside the burner cup on my stove, my suspicion is that the prong on my stove is actually a non-functional piece of metal serving as a placeholder for a thermocouple protection feature which Samsung could have opted to include on this burner, but chose not to. As to why it would prong-shaped instead of flat, I wonder if it has something to do with the gas flow being designed assuming presence of a thermocouple?

Comment: a thermocouple is an electrical device ... if there are no wires, then it is not a thermocouple

Comment: @jsotola agreed, I think this prong was pushed into the hole where a thermocouple would go had Samsung decided to fit this burner with a thermocouple.